# Why does ng-repeat gives many rows of output if I don't use track by

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular 1.2.7 and I am trying to use ng-repeat to give me three simple `<div>` elements with each showing one number. When I try the following with a very simple array I get 132 rows!

I have the following data in modal.data.subTopics:

[{"subTopicId":1,"number":1,"topicId":1,"objectiveDetailId":null,"name":" Architecture ","notes":" Java Architecture, Java Versions, Java History, Java Solutions","problems":[],"objectiveDetail":null},{"subTopicId":2,"number":2,"topicId":1,"objectiveDetailId":null,"name":" Usage ","notes":" java, javac","problems":[],"objectiveDetail":null},{"subTopicId":3,"number":3,"topicId":1,"objectiveDetailId":null,"name":" Utilities ","notes":" JAR","problems":[],"objectiveDetail":null}]

I have **exactly** the following HTML:

```
   XX {{ modal.data.subTopics }} XX
   <div data-ng-repeat="sT in modal.data.subTopics">{{ sT.subTopicId }}</div>
   YY
```

Here is what displays on the screen:

```
XX [{"subTopicId":1,"number":1,"topicId":1,"objectiveDetailId":null,"name":" Architecture ","notes":" Java Architecture, Java Versions, Java History, Java Solutions","problems":[],"objectiveDetail":null},{"subTopicId":2,"number":2,"topicId":1,"objectiveDetailId":null,"name":" Usage ","notes":" java, javac","problems":[],"objectiveDetail":null},{"subTopicId":3,"number":3,"topicId":1,"objectiveDetailId":null,"name":" Utilities ","notes":" JAR","problems":[],"objectiveDetail":null}] XX
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
YY
```

Update: When I use track by I get the following:

```
XX {{ modal.data.subTopics }} XX
<div data-ng-repeat="sT in modal.data.subTopics track by sT.subTopicId">{{ sT.subTopicId }}</div>
YY

XX [{"subTopicId":1,"number":1,"topicId":1,"objectiveDetailId":null,"name":" Architecture ","notes":" Java Architecture, Java Versions, Java History, Java Solutions","problems":[],"objectiveDetail":null},{"subTopicId":2,"number":2,"topicId":1,"objectiveDetailId":null,"name":" Usage ","notes":" java, javac","problems":[],"objectiveDetail":null},{"subTopicId":3,"number":3,"topicId":1,"objectiveDetailId":null,"name":" Utilities ","notes":" JAR","problems":[],"objectiveDetail":null}] XX
1
2
3
YY
```

But then an error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.7/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22fn%3A…Cf%2B%2B)%3Breturn%20f%7D%3B%20newVal%3A%2035%3B%20oldVal%3A%2032%22%5D%5D
    at Error (native)
    at http://127.0.0.1:82/Scripts/angular-v1.2.7/angular.min.js:6:449
    at h.$get.h.$digest (http://127.0.0.1:82/Scripts/angular-v1.2.7/angular.min.js:101:152)
    at h.$get.h.$apply (http://127.0.0.1:82/Scripts/angular-v1.2.7/angular.min.js:103:100)
    at HTMLTableRowElement.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:82/Scripts/angular-v1.2.7/angular.min.js:180:30)
    at HTMLTableRowElement.x.event.dispatch (http://127.0.0.1:82/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4:10006)
    at HTMLTableRowElement.x.event.add.y.handle (http://127.0.0.1:82/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4:6789) angular.min.js:84
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.7/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22fn%3A…Cf%2B%2B)%3Breturn%20f%7D%3B%20newVal%3A%2035%3B%20oldVal%3A%2032%22%5D%5D 
YY
```

Comment: Can u post ur controller code and full html also? From the output I am assuming the controller is getting initiated more than 1 time or the model is being initiated many times.

Comment: I will have a look into what's initiating the controller and also the model. What confuses me is that I check the value by printing it out inside {{ }} and then immediately after I have the ng-repeat. There's no lines in between. When I step through with debug my controller is initiated only once and the data all looks just as expected when I debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `modal` a property of `$scope` or `$rootScope`?

Either way, here's a JSBin with your data and it works fine:

http://jsbin.com/UqOdoYeq/1/edit

Without seeing your controller, it's hard to say what's happening, here. Do you have directives latching onto anything in code?

Comment: I defined it as $scope.modal = {};  then a bit later in the code: $scope.modal = { data: {} }; Then copy data into it like this:                         $scope.modal.data.subTopics = [
                            { "subTopicId": 1, "number": 1, "topicId": 1,  "name": " Architecture ", "notes": "xx" },
                            { "subTopicId": 2, "number": 2, "topicId": 1,  "name": " Usage ", "notes": "xx" },
                            { "subTopicId": 3, "number": 3, "topicId": 1,  "name": " Utilities ", "notes": "xx" }];
$scope.modal.backup = angular.copy($scope.modal.data);

Comment: I would do some more tracing with `console.log()`. Or take my JSBin and rebuild your app until it breaks!

Comment: Do you have any idea why I would get the different result when I added "track by" ?

Comment: I would imagine it's grouping up identical values? That's a lot of bloat and it'll probably get worse. I'd try my best to get to the root of the problem!

Comment: The problem was a <div> in the wrong place that surrounded the code. A bit difficult to describe but all working okay now. Thanks for your help / advice.